# Apply CSS for Razor control in Asp.Net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How do I apply width to razor control `@Html.RadioButtonFor` in mvc4?

UserModel.cs

```
public string Emp_Gender{get; set;}
```

index.cshtml

```
@model MvcApplication.Model.UserModel

@using (Html.BeingForm())
{
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.Emp_Gender,"Male")Male
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.Emp_Gender,"Female")Female
}
```

Answer (score 0):

razor:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.Emp_Gender,"Male", new { @class = "male"})Male
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.Emp_Gender,"Female", new { @class = "female"})Female
```

css:

```
input[type=radio].male {
   width: 150px;
}

input[type=radio].female {
   width: 300px;
}
```

However, bear in mind that browsers can be a bit finicky with the styling of radio buttons.
Check this link for information about what is possible:
http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/radio-button/
(a bit outdated, but still relevant)

Comment: it's work, and can we apply style separately.?   Like..................@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.Emp_Gender,"Male", new { @style = "width:100px"})Male

Comment: Yes. the second property of the "RadioButtonFor" method is a HtmlAttributes object, which allows you to specify any attributes to be included in the generated HTML element